# What is an appropriate length for function names?

Tags: coding-style, naming, documentation, methods, readability

I'm writing a C++ class, `CBookSpellDef` which has the following methods:

```
    int     GetIndexOf(const char *psz);
    char*   GetNameAtIndex(int index) { return m_spellTypes[index].szName; }
    char*   GetWeaponNameAtIndex(int index) { return m_spellTypes[index].szWeaponName; }
    int     GetBasePowerAtIndex(int index) { return m_spellTypes[index].iBasePower; }
    int     GetCostAtIndex(int index) { return m_spellTypes[index].iCost; }
    int     GetFlagsAtIndex(int index) { return m_spellTypes[index].iFlags; }
```

Compare to those of a very similar class, `CAmmoDef` from the Source SDK:

```
    int                 Index(const char *psz);
    int                 PlrDamage(int nAmmoIndex);
    int                 NPCDamage(int nAmmoIndex);
    int                 MaxCarry(int nAmmoIndex);
    int                 DamageType(int nAmmoIndex);
    int                 TracerType(int nAmmoIndex);
    float               DamageForce(int nAmmoIndex);
    int                 MinSplashSize(int nAmmoIndex);
    int                 MaxSplashSize(int nAmmoIndex);
    int                 Flags(int nAmmoIndex);
```

These are all simple methods which return values from an instance of a struct at an index of a member array of the class, said instance representing magic book spells in the case of `CBookSpellDef`, or ammunition types in the case of `CAmmoDef`.

Are my names "too descriptive" while the ones from the Source SDK are the right length? What would the appropriate length and level of "descriptiveness" for these method names be?

Comment: What's `CBookSpellDef`? How is it different from just a `Spell`?

Comment: @Alexander similar to how `CAmmoDef` manages all of the ammo types in Half-Life 2 and other Source games, `CBookSpellDef` manages the types of magic spells in my game, which work very similarly to ammo in other Source games.

Comment: I'm not familiar with it. What's with the `C` prefix and `Def` suffix?

Comment: @Alexander I don't know, I'm just using them to comply with the naming scheme already present in the Source SDK.

Comment: There's room to cargo-cult practices you don't (yet) understand, but this seems like one you should understand before using

Comment: Be as brief as you can while conveying the important semantic information not implied by the context (namespace, class, function-signature) and avoiding all but ubiquitous abbreviations. Common conventions (especially automation-related ones) trump those considerations though.

Answer (score 4):

The difference here isn’t length as much as warts. You’re cluttering your names with structural information that says “this is a getter” and “pass an index”. The other names have those exact same structural considerations but only use the name to convey semantics. No structural warts. The semantic names make a lot clear on their own but to learn the signature you look at the signature.

Names-with-warts is simply a different style. It’s not at all required. If you remove the warts I’m sure I can handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Both sets of method names seem quite reasonable, abstractly.

Being reasonably systematic about naming is important. And being somewhat thoughtful about names is important.

But it's impossible to say whether exactly 6 or 7 characters is too many.

As a guideline off the cuff, I'd say around 6 to 15 characters for a name is quite ordinary.

Shorter names are good so long as their meaning is clear. And longer names inherently have a cost in terms of reduced readability and visual clutter - so that has to be balanced against any benefit of a long name.

The design of the naming scheme really depends on how many things need to be distinguished in context. That means not only the context of the application, but the context of different areas and scopes in an application, and also the context of the programmer's wider work.

Because strangers don't have access to that context and because it can be enormously difficult to describe all the relevant context, that's what stops there being a simple set of rules for how to name things which can be written down.